# Smartstore.net how to enable import products option

Tags: excel, content-management-system

I and My Friend have installed latest version of smartstore.net on our local system.

While using the admin section he accidently configured an option which on product add page he can see import product from excel and export button. Same is not visible on my system.

I have searched extensively but I am not able to find the samething. Can any body suggest me way where I can see import product from excel option.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your product data by using an import profile. To create an import profile, go to **Configuration > Import**.

Good luck.